# Text and Icon in Button with Condition

Tags: reactjs

How can I add both icon and text in a button with conditional rendering

This is working
`<button >{this.state.isLoading ? <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> : "Submit"}</button>`

This is working
`<button >{this.state.isLoading ? "Submitting..." : "Submit"}</button>`

This is NOT working
`<button >{this.state.isLoading ? <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> "Submitting..." : "Submit"}</button>`

Comment: any errors ?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react you can have only one root element, your code look like 2 elements ex: `<i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>` and `Submitting...` you should wrap these elements into one root element.

```
<button >{this.state.isLoading ? <><i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> "Submitting..."</> : "Submit"}</button>
```

learn more about [fragments from here](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
<button >{this.state.isLoading ? <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> "Submitting..." : "Submit"}</button>
```

to

```
<button >{this.state.isLoading ?<div> <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> "Submitting..."</div> : "Submit"}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to return both as a button

```
 {count ?<button> <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>Submitting...</button> : <button>submitted</button>}
```